# Load multiple files content to table using SQL loader

Tags: oracle, command-prompt, sql-loader

How to insert data from multiple files having different columns into a table in Oracle database using SQL Loader with Single control file.

Basically ,

We have 3 CSV files

1. file 1 having columns a,b,c
2. file 2 having columns d,e,f
3. file 3 having columns g,h,i

We need to insert the above attributes to a Table named "TableTest"
having columns a,b,c ,d,e,f,g,h,i

Using single control file

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this out - [Link Fixed](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#Can_one_load_data_from_multiple_files.2F_into_multiple_tables_at_once.3F)

Comment: Even if you could I would advise against it as there is no way to guarantee data integrity.  At a minimum each row in each file needs a key that is unique across all three files in order to build the row.  You will need a procedure to read these files, using that key to ensure you indeed matched up all components of that row before inserting into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't.  You can either splice the .csv files together (a lot of nasty work) or create 3 tables to load and then use plsql or sql to join them together into your target table.